# How to validate that 4 fields are not repeated in any manner

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I have a form with a form with 4 fields that are cellphones, I need to validate that neither of those 4 fields are repeated within them.

I didnt develop this myself, this was done by one of our devs, so I wonder if there is a way to do this in one line with linq or dictionaries?

```
private bool Celularesvalidation(string c1, string c2, string c3, string c4)
{
    var rs = false;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c2))
    {
        if (c1 == c2)
        {
            rs = true;
        }
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c3))
    {
        if (c3 == c1 || c3 == c2)
        {
            rs = true;
        }
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c4))
    {
        if (c4 == c1 || c4 == c2 || c4 == c3)
        {
            rs = true;
        }
    }

    return rs;
}
```

Comment: first question I would ask is `Do you even understand the code that's been handed to / given to you`? learn lambda expressions you could do this in so many different ways.. also ..there are plenty of examples on the web on how to do this..

Comment: I DO understand it but its very ugly, so I wonder if there is a one liner code to do that validation

Comment: This code only allows `c1` to be `nullOrEmpty` and still return `true`. Is that by design or is it a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an idea:

```
var cellphones = new string[] { c1, c2, c3, c4 };
bool allDistinct = cellphones.Distinct().Count() == cellphones.Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the distinct records and compare.

```
private bool Celularesvalidation(string c1, string c2, string c3, string c4)
{
    var cellPhones = new[] { c1,c2,c3,c4};
    var distinctCellPhones   = cellPhones.Distinct();
    return  distinctCellPhones.Count() < cellPhones.Count();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can do it in one line if you really want to. This example also includes enforcing that none of them are null or empty:

```
private bool CelularesValidation(string c1, string c2, string c3, string c4)
{
    return new[] { c1, c2, c3, c4 }.Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c))
        .Distinct().Count() == 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing same thing

[image: Using Linqpad]

```
   var list = new List<string> { c1, c2, c3, c4 };
    var result = list.GroupBy(l => l, (a, b) => new { Key = a, Count = b.Count() }).Where(obj => obj.Count > 1 && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(obj.Key)).FirstOrDefault() != null;
    result.Dump();
```

Comment: I dont really understand this one, can you ellaborate?

Comment: @LuisValencia-MVP I added an image to the solution, Best way to see this in action is using Linqpad. First does a group by and using the grouping for each it will check is any one of them is repeated and if repeated , returns true.